# In core plot 1.0 how do you clear a plot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I am using Core Plot 1.0.  I have successfully made an XY scatter plot in my tabbed app.  However when I leave the tab with the graph, enter different data, and go back to the tab with the new graph, both graphs appear.  I have seen some commands like [graph reloadData] but that option didnt come up.  Perhaps that's from another version.  So can anyone help me clear one graph to get ready to display another?  Do I need to place a command in the viewdidload method or something similar?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "both graphs appear"? Did you add another plot without removing the first one?

Comment: @EricSkroch, Yes I added another without removing the first.  I see in your answer below that I need to call the method -reloadData.  Where do I place this.  And do you have a link to some documentation.  I have been looking all over the Core Plot website.  Thanks again.

Comment: The docs are linked from the Core Plot home page; the iOS docs are [here](http://core-plot.googlecode.com/hg/documentation/html/iOS/index.html). The docs are also included with the downloadable release packages in both docset and HTML format.

Comment: This was answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12133332/core-plot-1-0-how-to-implement-reloaddata-method/12150376#12150376

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph has a `-reloadData` method. You call this to have all plots in the graph refresh their entire dataset. You can call `-reloadData` on individual plots, too, if you only need to update some of them. Call this method from the main thread in your app when the new data is available to the datasource.

Comment: I set up all the data for my plot in the viewDidAppear method.  I am basically taking some data and placing it in an NSMutableArray.  So I placed [self.hostView.hostedGraph reloadData]; at the beginning of that method.  But nothing happened.  At the end of viewDidAppear, I call a method to make the graph  `- (void)initPlot
{
    [self configureHost];
    [self configureGraph];
    [self configurePlots];
    [self configureAxes];
}` Should I place it in one of these methods?  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I found the reloadData method.  But I am confused, do I make that method, or call it at a certain time?  do you have a sample I can look at?  Thanks again, I just started teaching myself core plot, it is quite powerful, but a ste learning curve!

Comment: It's a method you call to tell the graph or plot that you have new data available for it. The plot(s) will discard all of the old data, call their respective datasources to retrieve the new data, and redraw. Don't call `reloadData` until the new data is available, i.e., your array is filled. You don't have to call it on a new plot—it will load its data the first time Core Animation tries to draw it. Make sure you look at the example apps included with Core Plot (in the examples folder).

Comment: I see in APYahooDataPullerGraph.m you have the method reloadData.  This is where you make the graph, but then you use [graph reloadData] with in that method.  First, I don't understand that.  Second, if I made my graph in a method called initPlot, do I need to make another method that does all the same things in reloadData?  Sorry for all the questions but I am not wrapping my brain around this one at all!?

Comment: Another note.  I see all the release and auto release.  I am using ARC.  Is this going to make a big difference?  Thanks again.

Comment: The graph is built in `-viewDidLoad`. The `-dataPullerDidFinishFetch:` method is a delegate method for the class that loads the plot data from the web. It updates the plot ranges and calls `-reloadData` to tell the graph that new data is available from the datasource.

Comment: re: ARC, Core Plot and all of the example apps use manual memory management for the widest compatibility between platforms (Mac and iOS) and system versions. You can use Core Plot in apps that use garbage collection or ARC, too.